# DATE Constraint is ignored on insert

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, constraint, check-constraints

I must be missing something somewhere..

Azure SQL

```
DispatchedOn is a DateTime column

ALTER TABLE [table] WITH CHECK ADD CONSTRAINT [CK_ReportDate6MonthRollGreater] CHECK  ((CONVERT([date],[DispatchedOn])>='2022-12-07'))
GO

ALTER TABLE [table] CHECK CONSTRAINT [CK_ReportDate6MonthRollGreater]
GO
```

I can insert a date of 2022-12-01

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SQL Server will allow insertion of dates that violate the `CHECK` constraint when the `CHECK_CONSTRAINTS` option is omitted from a T-SQL `BULK INSERT`, BCP in, or SSIS destination. Furthermore, the constraint is marked as non-trusted after the operation to indicate existing data may violate the constraint.

Run this query to verify the constraint is trusted and enabled:

```
SELECT 
      name
    , is_disabled
    , is_not_trusted 
FROM sys.check_constraints 
WHERE name = N'CK_ReportDate6MonthRollGreater';
```

Comment: This is it...the data is loaded via BULK insert. Need to add that option.

Answer (score 1):

The strings '2022-12-07' and '2022-12-01' in your examples are ambiguous.

- '2022-12-07' might mean 7 December 2022 or 12 July 2022.
- '2022-12-01' might mean 1 December 2022 or 12 January 2022.

For example:

```
SET LANGUAGE English;
SELECT English = CONVERT(datetime, '2022-12-07');
SET LANGUAGE British;
SELECT British = CONVERT(datetime, '2022-12-07');
```

| English |
| --- |
| 2022-12-07 00:00:00.000 |

| British |
| --- |
| 2022-07-12 00:00:00.000 |

The rendering also depends on client settings like OS language.

There might be some combination of language or format setting in your database or display client that allows the combination shown. For example, 1 December 2022 is legitimately after 12 July 2022.

To avoid such issues, always use `CONVERT` with a **deterministic style** when converting dates and times *to or from* a string format.

This is documented in [Nondeterministic conversion of literal date strings into DATE values](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/nondeterministic-convert-date-literals)

Example:

```
SELECT 
    TheDate =
        CONVERT
        (
            char(24), 
            CONVERT
            (
                datetime, 
                '2022-12-07', 
                -- interpret string as ODBC canonical
                -- yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss (24-hour)
                120
            ), 
            -- format as Europe default
            -- dd mon yyyy hh:mi:ss:mmm (24-hour)
            113
        );
```

| TheDate |
| --- |
| 07 Dec 2022 00:00:00:000 |

There are reasons to doubt this is the cause in your particular case, making Dan's answer more likely, but it is still best practice and will help you eliminate a possible source of confusion.

Comment: I thought this too, for a minute and verified it wasn't it. But good call out to be more defensive in the code.